# 3D quadrilateral mesh using Mayavi

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi

I have an array of 3D coordinates of a mesh, where each four rows represent a mesh face.

**Data**:

```
X11,Y11,Z11
X12,Y12,Z12
X13,Y13,Z13
X14,Y14,Z14
...
XN1,YN1,ZN1
XN2,YN2,ZN2
XN3,YN3,ZN3
XN4,YN4,ZN4
```

where `N` is the total number of mesh faces

Does anyone know the best way to display this mesh using Mayavi/matplotlib?